# How to remove character that is NOT [ACGTN] with SED

Tags: linux, unix, sed

How can I replace any string that is not "A", "C", "G", "T", "N", with sed?

For example I have the following data:

```
>AFCCCCC 1
cagktgagtgataaggc
>AFCGH22 1
cagntgagtgstaaggc
```

What I want to remove every character that is not [ACGTN] in line that do not start with '>'

Hence I hope to get this output:

```
 >AFCCCCC 1
 cagtgagtgataaggc
 >AFCGH22 1
 cagntgagtgtaaggc
```

Note that I removed 'k' and 's' for first and second sequence.

Comment: Why do you not remove `c`?  Are you interested in deleting characters not in the set `ACGTNacgtn`, or merely not in the set `acgtn`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/^>/!s/[^ACGTN]//ig' input.txt
```

Comment: Note that the `i` flag is a gnu extension and is not recognized by all sed.